# Problem when accessing some routes from my LARAVEL 8 api

Tags: laravel, api

I have created an api with Laravel 8, very simple, just to do some tests, it is a table with users where I store their name, last name and city.

Well my problem is to obtain all the users that are in the database and when making a POST and add a new one, i can make a GET to see a specific user, I can also update users and delete them, so I do not understand why I can not add them and see all that there is.

Here is the code

UsuarioController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Usuario;



class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = Usuario::all();

        return response()->json($usuarios);
    }
  
    public function show($id)
    {
        $Usuario = Usuario::find($id);

        if (!$Usuario) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Usuario not found'], 404);
        }

        return response()->json($Usuario);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $usuario = new Usuario();
    
        $usuario->nombre = $request->input('nombre');
        $usuario->apellidos = $request->input('apellidos');
        $usuario->ciudad = $request->input('ciudad');
    
        $usuario->save();
    
        return response()->json($usuario, 201);
    }
    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $usuario = Usuario::find($id);
    
        if (!$usuario) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Usuario not found'], 404);
        }
    
        $usuario->nombre = $request->input('nombre');
        $usuario->apellidos = $request->input('apellidos');
        $usuario->ciudad = $request->input('ciudad');
    
        $usuario->save();
    
        return response()->json($usuario);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $Usuario = Usuario::find($id);

        if (!$Usuario) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Usuario not found'], 404);
        }

        $Usuario->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Usuario deleted']);
    }
}
```

Routes/Api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Usuario;
use App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::get('/usuarios', [UsuarioController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/usuarios', [UsuarioController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/usuarios/{id}', [UsuarioController::class, 'show']);
Route::put('/usuarios/{id}', [UsuarioController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/usuarios/{id}', [UsuarioController::class, 'destroy']);
```

And Models/Usuario.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'apellidos', 'ciudad'];
   
    protected $table =  'usuarios';
}
```

I use this url "http://localhost:8000/api/usuarios" and i get 404 not found, but i dont understand why if others request like put works
[image]

Comment: you haven't defined the problem, you are just describing what you can do ... what is the actual problem?

Comment: Ok, but show in Postman where you post your create route, etc, show the error message, find the error message in your laravel.log and copy the entire stacktrace in your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're adding an extra space/line right after URL in postman, please trim it

Comment: I do this but not works, i get 404 not found

Comment: @verosf98 try `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: still does not work

Comment: @verosf98 you said update and delete API works, share the URLs of them

Comment: this  for get a specific user `http://localhost:8000/api/usuarios/1` and the same tu update only change to PUT the select with the request types

Comment: @verosf98 try running `php artisan route:list` and check whether route is actually registered or not

Comment: all are shown in the list

Comment: @verosf98 then it should work, restart server once and check

Comment: @verosf98 add attachment of your postman error in actual question

Comment: I don't understand what's going on, I'm going crazy, nothing is working.

Comment: @verosf98 I think you're adding an extra space or line right after URL in postman, because I can see that (enter sign) , please trim it